# how to make text have different shades of pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, text, pixel, scanning

i scanned a document. the scanned text has different shades of pixels in the letters, like the picture 'ty'. is there an easy way to recreate that? the outer edging also appears darker while the inside is lighter.

[image: scanned text comes in different shades]

when i type new text, and select a color, all the pixels inside become that one shade, like the picture 'oy'. both edging and inside are the same shade.

[image]

thanks

Comment: You could always Photoshop what you want typed. Print it. And then scan it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new layer **(⌘/cntrl+⇧+N)**
2. Press (**⇧+delete**) or (**⇧+f5**) and set the Contents on **50% Gray**, press ok

[image]

3. Select your Grey layer and apply Noise **25%**, **Unifrom**, tick **Monochromatic**  (**Filter>Noise>Add Noise**)

[image]

4. Apply to the same layer a **Mosaic** filter at **9 Square** cell size (**Filters>Pixelate>Mosaic**)
   [image]
5. Type in your test and drag it underneath the grey layer
6. Right Click Grey layer and **Create Clip Mask**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Right, now once all this is done, you can ether way apply a adjustment layer to tone down the pixels if you need them a bit darker.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Enjoy :]  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the textured background, and the different *shades* of pixels are coming from that - the best way to do this is with layer styles on the text layer itself.

Set the fill color of the text to a dark grey color and set the blending mode - I would have said to use 'Multiply' but 'Linear Burn' gave me the best result. Just use whatever works best for you. Give the text layer an Inner Shadow to give the slight stroke effect.

[image]

Find whatever combination of settings works for you - Blending modes, opacity, color, Shadow Choke/Size etc.

**This is what I came up with in 2 minutes.**

[image]

It isn't perfect but it is close and you could probably do better with a bit more time and attention.